# Clojure failing to print non-ASCII chars on OS X

Tags: java, macos, character-encoding, clojure

I've installed Clojure 1.2.0 using Homebrew package management system on Mac OS X 10.6.4. Running:

```
$ clj -e '(println "русский язык\n")'
```

in the Terminal results in:

```
??????? ????
```

While running in the same terminal:

```
$ php -r 'echo "русский язык\n";'
```

displays the Cyrillic text correctly.

The same effect when running `$ clj <some .clj file in UTF-8 encoding>`

Is that a known issue? Java Runtime-related? I thought at this point languages finally *get* Unicode right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the default java file.endcoding on osx is Mac Roman, you need to -D set it to utf8

Comment: Yep, adding -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 to java command line solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you're using the bundled `clj` script, the easiest thing to do is add the `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` to the java commands in there.

Answer (score 0):

Read http://groups.google.ru/group/clojure-russian/browse_thread/thread/56da274ad22a75df
for clojure and russian language bugs and solutions.